# Webpack exclude 3rd party libraries installed via npm

Tags: javascript, webpack

As for fun I am developing my own html/css admin panel theme migrating from old codebase into webpack as an attempt to make it more modular. Also I use it as an excuse for learning webpack and making my frontend code more test friendly.

My webpack config is:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        __dirname+"/assets/js/panel.js",
    ],
    output: {
      path: __dirname+'/www',
      publicPath: '/',
      filename: 'panel.js'
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
           test: /\.css$/,
           use: [
            'style-loader',
            'css-loader',
           ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [ 
              {
                loader:'style-loader',
              },
              // Translates CSS into CommonJS
              {
                loader:'css-loader'
              },
              // Compiles Sass to CSS
              {
                loader:'sass-loader'
              },
            ],
        },
        {
            test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            use: [
              { 
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                  name: '[name].[ext]',
                  outputPath: 'fonts/'
               }
              }
            ]
        }
      ],
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'www'),
        compress: true,
        port: 8000
    }
  };
```

And my `assets/js/panel.js` is considted of the following code:

```
// 3rd party libs
import $ from 'jquery';
import bsBreakpoints from 'bs-breakpoints'
import 'bootstrap';
import _ from 'lodash';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/fontawesome'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/solid' // https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&s=solid&m=free
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/regular' // https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&s=regular&m=free
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/brands' // https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&s=brands&m=free


// Rest of the code is here
```

Also my `package.json` is consisted by this settings:

```
{
  "name": "ellakcy_admin",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Admin HTML/CSS template using Bootstrap",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --compress"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "html",
    "css",
    "admin"
  ],
  "author": "Cypriot FOSS Community",
  "license": "GPL",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.4.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "bs-breakpoints": "^1.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery-ui-dist": "^1.12.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "saas": "^1.0.0",
    "script-loader": "^0.7.2",
    "lodash": ">=4.17.13",
    "lodash.template": ">=4.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.7.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "file-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0",
    "clean-css": ">=4.1.11"
  }
}
```

So, many themes are being shipped without its 3rd party dependencies so when I build with the js and css with webpack how I can exclude them? I mean it is pointless to ship eg. fontawesome or bootstrap.